# How to persist a function pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, jit

Suppose that I have a function pointer which can be invoked to do some tasks. How can I store the piece of code, to which the pointer is pointing, to a file on disk so I can later load the file and have the function pointer available again?

Use case: This will be done inside a JIT compiler to prevent the future overhead of JIT-ing in the next run of the same program.

Edit: The answer to "[Save and load function pointers to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518367/save-and-load-function-pointers-to-file)" are not what I am looking for. That question is dealing with a limited number of functions to which people have suggested using indices. But in my case, the function can be anything with any content.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do. There's no standard way of doing that in C (although there may be solutions for your problem on your particular OS).

Comment: Can you explain the use case a bit more?

Comment: This question is far too broad.

Comment: @MichaelWalz After editing I think it is a good question

Comment: hmm.. not sure. If you're able to JIT, storing the code shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: incidentally, there was a question lately about replacing main with an array, and a link to a guy who did that with a bit of reverse engineering (neither linker nor the C runtime care enough about the types of symbols to complain about an array called `main`; whatever is in there is subject to execution, so to speak.) If that byte sequence does not contain absolute addresses it could be written to disk and reloaded later.

Comment: The link to main-as-array is [here](http://jroweboy.github.io/c/asm/2015/01/26/when-is-main-not-a-function.html).

Comment: Hm... my intuition is to have your program generate a shared library with the JITed code in that and then load the shared library with `dlopen()` every time you need it. That's going to be complex to implement for sure though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save and load function pointers to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518367/save-and-load-function-pointers-to-file)

Answer (score 5):

There is no portable way to do that. Your options are:

- Associate pointers with symbolic names of your choosing, e.g. using a global mapping table, and serialize the function name. On deserialization, look up the actual pointer in the mapping.
- Serialize real function names, possibly also contained with a mapping. On deserialization, use [`dlsym`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) (or equivalent on non-Unix platforms, such as [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx)) to get the function pointer.